# How to add ARC for a single .dylib file

Tags: ios, xcode, core-image, dylib, dynamic-library

In the recent Penetration test of our iOS app we found a vulnerability that {appName}.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib does not enforce automatic reference counting protection.How to enable the ARC for .dylib files, I could not find the file anywhere in the project, please help me in fixing this.Thanks

I have tried adding ARC flag to the individual pod class file which is the only file that is using coreImage framework, but file is written in objective-c.

Comment: You should probably file a Feedback for that, and maybe also ask in the Developer Forums. It seems like an oversight on Apple's side.

Comment: hi @FrankRupprecht , adding arc flag to the file which uses the library(like I have tried) would not have any effect on this issue?

Comment: It seems the lib is pre-built by Apple and bundled with an app on demand. You can find it in `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib`.